# Abrir meu App de um link enviado via email

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, ionic

Estou tentando fazer com que o usuário, ao clicar no link recebido via email, seja redirecionado para uma view específica do meu aplicativo. Seria algo do tipo: 'myapp://app-custom-path'. Estou usando Ionic. Alguem poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Instala este plugin.Acredito que vá te ajudar https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia utilizar o plugin Custom URL scheme Cordova/PhoneGap Plugin, conforme citado pelo colega.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-customurlscheme --variable URL_SCHEME=ionicapp
```

Utilizando suas url's desta forma:

```
ionicapp://
```

E no aplicativo para utilizar a url:

```
var handleOpenURL = function(url) {
    alert("RECEIVED URL: " + url);
};
```

Comment: desculpe a ignorância, achei muito interessante a pergunta do nosso colega, para fazer isso o app deve estar na nuvem?

Comment: Falando em app, não seria necessariamente em nuvem, pois temos varios SOs, android, ios entre outros.

Comment: Achei interessante, mas como o cara recebe o link de algo que não está disponível em um servidor por exemplo. Se alguém tiver um material sobre isso para me passar, estou dando uma pesquisada aqui também, mas não achei nada.

Comment: @i9oni9on pesquise por **deep link** ou **deep linking**, tem uma matéria [aqui](https://medium.com/@JohnCalistro/o-que-%C3%A9-deep-linking-d0208d746874) explicando como funciona pra web e em dispositivos moveis.